# Display react component in route only when accessed in a specific way

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, show-hide, react-component

I'm planning to display a success message only when a specific model pass some tests. I don't want this page/component to be displayed if the user alters the URL or by any other means not being through the process I described. Any Idea how to do that using react route and possibly states, cryptography  if needed. To simplify things at the beginning I would like to display the message only when redirected through a specific button click action.

Comment: You need to use programmatic routing

Comment: Add a global state to the application, when button is clicked set this global state and redirect. And then on the next page check whether state is set or not and do action accordingly. You can use context for global state.